# jQuery-fileupload: start file upload manually from outside the plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

Is it possible to start [jQuery fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) from outside the plugin? I want to start it manually after another form has completed an ajax request, but I'm not sure how to.

```
$('form#attachment').bindUploadUploader()
jQuery.fn.bindUploadUploader = function() {
  return $(this).fileupload({
    autoUpload: false
  });
};    

$('#upload').on('ajax:success', function() {
  // Start upload here
});
```

There are some [examples here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously), [and here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#programmatic-file-upload), but the all deal with submitting the first form from within the `add` callback, still inside the plugin.